# how to preview images previously uploaded to the server?

Tags: angularjs, ng-file-upload

I am using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload) and I want to know how to show images which were uploaded previously to the server using ngf-thumbnail?

Comment: Something like this: `<img ngf-thumbnail="/url/of/the/image/on/the/server/img.jpg"` You need to serve the files that are uploaded on your server to be able to be downloaded and this depends on your server implementation. You can upload them on a static folder that will be automatically available on your server or have your server make those files available for download.

Answer (score 0):

`ng-file-upload` really great angular plugin to work with files. Also it has really good documented.

After adding control to process files:

```
<div ngf-drop="" ng-model="files" ngf-model-options="modelOptionsObj" ngf-multiple="multiple" ngf-pattern="'image/*'" ... />
```

You can access this files to show in preview using `ngf-src` directive

```
      <div class="preview">
        <img ngf-src="!files[0].$error && files[0]">
      </div>
```

For better understanding and more behaviors supported by this plugin please follow this demo link

https://angular-file-upload.appspot.com/